# Use VI keys everywhere instead of cursor keys

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

I like VIM a lot because it kind of doubles the power of my keyboard in a way. It's either in insert or motion or whatever they call it mode.
Navigating through source code, typing code, while being able to keep my hands in the touch type position is great.
But when a dialog box is opened (eg. the one using ctrl+F12), if I have to select something other than the first one in the list, I am forced to have to move my right hand to the cursor keys.
Is there a way so that I can use J and K or else something with ctrl or alt or something, so that I can select an item while keeping my hands in the touch typing position?

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine shortcuts for the Up, Down, Left, Right actions in File | Settings | Keymap (the regular keymap that has nothing to do with IdeaVim). IdeaVim provides Vim emulation only for code editors like file editors, interactive language consoles, etc.

**Edit**: I guess you can't use `j` and `k` since characters typed in the structure window are reserved for searching. But you can use `Ctrl+N` and `Ctrl+P` which is the same as the navigation shortcuts for pop-up windows in Vim.

**Edit 2**: You can't use `Ctrl+N` and `Ctrl+P` as well due to [this bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-125655) in IntelliJ.

Comment: I tried mapping Ctrl+N to Down, but when I bring up the Ctrl+F12 popup, it does not navigate down. I tried assigning Ctrl+N to VIM and to IDE, but neither makes it work.

Comment: @Mike You're right. I've found [this bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-125655) in the IntelliJ's issue tracker.

Comment: Wauw, found 4 or 5 related bug reports the one you links to, as well. Started around 2012 from the looks of it. Must be a very low priority item.
I think how I might solve it, is by deciding on a more permanent solution, which is to add keybindings on the OS level. Ctrl+Alt+N/P or Ctrl+Alt+J/K.